# scatter plot specifying color and labelling axis in r

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have following data and plot:

```
pos <- rep(1:2000, 20)
xv =c(rep(1:20, each = 2000))
# colrs <- unique(xv)
colrs <- xv # edits 
yv =rnorm(2000*20, 0.5, 0.1)

xv   = lapply(unique(xv), function(x) pos[xv==x])
to.add = cumsum(sapply(xv, max) + 1000)

bp <- c(xv[[1]], unlist(lapply(2:length(xv), function(x) xv[[x]] + to.add[x-1])))
plot (bp,yv, pch = "*", col = colrs)
```

[image]

I have few issues in this plot I could not figure out.

(1) I want to use different color for different group or two different color for different groups (i.e xv), but when I tried color function in terms to be beautiful mixture. Although I need to highlight some points (for example bp 4000 to 4500 for example with blue color)

(2) Instead of bp positions I want to put a tick mark and label with the group.

Thank you, appreciate your help.

Edits: with help of the following answer (with slight different approach in case I have unbalanced number in each group will work) I could get the similar plot. But still question remaining regarding colors is what if I want to use two alternate colors in alternate group ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain (to me at least) what you mean by 'two alternate colors in alternate group'. Do you mean two colours scattered within one another or each alternate group gets a different colour (eg: red/blue/red/blue)

Comment: yes I mean first category will get red, then second blue then red and then blue to end of the plot

Comment: Would this do the trick? `plot (bp,yv, pch = "*", col = rep(c("red","blue"),each=2000,times=10),xaxt="n");
axis(1,at=seq(1000,58000,3000),labels=1:20,cex.axis=0.7,las=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your colour issue by repeating the colour index however many times each group has a point plotted, like so:

```
plot (bp,yv, pch = "*", col = rep(colrs,each=2000))
```

The default colour palette (see `?palette` or `palette()` ) will wrap around itself and you might want to specify your own to get 20 distinct colours.

To relabel the x axis, try plotting without the axis and then specifying the points and labels manually.

```
plot (bp,yv, pch = "*", col = rep(colrs,each=2000),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=seq(1000,58000,3000),labels=1:20)
```

If you are trying to squeeze a lot of labels in there, you might have to shrink the text (`cex.axis`)or spin the labels 90 degrees (`las=2`).

```
plot (bp,yv, pch = "*", col = rep(colrs,each=2000),xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=seq(1000,58000,3000),labels=1:20,cex.axis=0.7,las=2)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is you could use a nested `ifelse`.
I'm still learning `R`, but one way it could be done would look something like:

```
plot(whatev$x, whatev$y, col=ifelse(xv<2000,red,ifelse(2000<xv & xv<4000,yellow,blue)))
```

You could nest as many of these as you want to have specificity on the colors and the intervals. The `ifelse` command is of form `ifelse(TEST, True, False)`.

A simpler way would be to use the unique groups in xv to assign rainbow colors.

```
colrs=rainbow(length(unique(xv)))  #Or colrs=rainbow(length(xv)) if xv is unique.
plot(whatev$x, whatev$y, col=colrs)
```

I hope I got all that right. I'm still learning R myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your real data are something like 2000 values of things from 20 different groups. For instance, heights of 2000 plants of 20 different species. In such a case, you might want to look at the `dotplot()` function (or as illustrated below, `dotplot.table()`) in the `lattice` package.

Generate matrix of hypothetical values:

```
set.seed(1)

myY <- sapply( seq_len(20), function(x) rnorm(2000, x^(1/3)))
```

Transpose matrix to get groups as rows

```
myY <- t(myY)
```

Provide names of groups to matrix:

```
dimnames(myY)[[1]]<-paste("group", seq_len(nrow(myY)))
```

Load `lattice` package

```
library(lattice)
```

Generate dotplot

```
dotplot(myY, horizontal = FALSE, panel = function(x, y, horizontal, ...) {
  panel.dotplot(x = x, y = y, horizontal = horizontal, jitter.x = TRUE,
    col = seq_len(20)[x], pch = "*", cex = 1.5)
  }, scales = list(x = list(rot = 90))
)
```

Which looks like (with unfortunate y-axis labeling):

[image: a dotplot]

Comment: this nice plot ...it might be helpful for other instances but in my case it not just group but value of x on the axis matters ...thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that @JohnCLK is requesting a way of colouring by values on the `x` axis, I tried these demos in `ggplot2`-- each uses a dummy variable that is coded based on values or ranges to be highlighted in the other variables.

So, first set up the data, as in the question:

```
pos <- rep(1:2000, 20)
xv <- c(rep(1:20, each = 2000))
yv <- (2000*20, 0.5, 0.1)
xv <- lapply(unique(xv), function(x) pos[xv==x])
to.add <- cumsum(sapply(xv, max) + 1000)
bp <- c(xv[[1]], unlist(lapply(2:length(xv), function(x) xv[[x]] + to.add[x-1])))
```

Then load `ggplot2`, prepare a couple of utility functions, and set the default theme:

```
library("ggplot2")

make.png <- function(p, fName) {
    png(fName, width=640, height=480, units="px")
    print(p)
    dev.off()
}

make.plot <- function(df) {
    p <- ggplot(df, 
                aes(x = bp,
                    y = yv, 
                    colour = highlight))
    p <- p + geom_point()
    p <- p + opts(legend.position = "none")
    return(p)
}

theme_set( theme_bw() )
```

Draw a plot which highlights values in a defined range on the vertical axis:

```
# highlight a horizontal band
df <- data.frame(cbind(bp, yv))
df$highlight <- 0
df$highlight[ df$yv >= 0.4 & df$yv < 0.45 ] <- 1
p <- make.plot(df)
print(p)
make.png(p, "demo_horizontal.png")
```

[image: Horizontal band]

Next draw a plot which highlights values in a defined range on the `x` axis, a vertical band:

```
# highlight a vertical band
df$highlight <- 0
df$highlight[ df$bp >= 38000 & df$bp < 42000 ] <- 1
p <- make.plot(df)
print(p)
make.png(p, "demo_vertical.png")
```

[image: Vertical band]

And finally draw a plot which highlights alternating vertical bands, by `x` value:

```
# highlight alternating bands
library("gtools")
alt.band.width <- 2000
df$highlight <- as.integer(df$bp / alt.band.width)
df$highlight <- ifelse(odd(df$highlight), 1, 0)
p <- make.plot(df)
print(p)
make.png(p, "demo_alternating.png")
```

[image: Alternating bands]

Hope this helps; it was good practice anyway.